# is it necessary to download all the dependencies and the full target file to compile and build any contract?

Tags: substrate-node-template, ink, rust, pallet-contracts, cargo-contract

due to I have limited internet in my country , I can not download the full building files after I wrote the contract and need to only see if there are any errors and need to run the tests .
so if I tried to build the contract by this command , it downloads the target directory as shown :

```rust
cargo contract build
```

because the downloaded files have a size of 3 gigabytes as shown [image]

### so I need a way to compile my contract and see all the errors and the messages for learning purposes without me having to download all of this files online

Comment: The target folder does not come only from downloading, part of it are the compiled files created by the compiler.

That said I don't know how much it downloads.
Also downloads can actually be downloaded to `.cargo/` folder (on linux at least)

But I don't have solutions. Maybe connecting to a remote server and doing development from there can cost less bandwidth?